# flutter anonymous / inline functions for widget properties

Tags: dart, inline-functions

I am new to dart and flutter, I am trying to use an inline function to return a value.

```
SizedBox(
  height: _getheight()
),

double _getheight(){
//do some stuff
return 20.0;
}
//WORKS
```

```
SizedBox(
height: (){return 20.0;}
),
//(Won't build)
```

error: The argument type 'double Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.

```
SizedBox(
 height: (){return 20.0;} as double
),
```

--builds but fails during runtime
error: type '() => double' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`height` are taking a value of the type `double`. In you first example, you are executing `_getheight()` and then gives the result of this execution as the parameter named `height`.

In you second example you are trying to give `height` an function as argument (typed as `double Function()`) which are not allowed since `height` is defined to take a `double`.

You could then do:

```
SizedBox(
height: (){return 20.0;}()
),
```

Which will execute the method (see the last `()`) and use the returned value as argument to `height`.

Comment: Thanks! makes perfect sense, I was never executing the inline function.