# Can I have a Function as the children parameter in Columns and Rows

Tags: flutter

Right now what I do is this:

```dart
Row(children: generateWidgets(numbers))

List<Widget> generateWidgets(List<String> numbers){
  final widgets List<Widget> = [];

  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    widgets.add(Text(numbers[i]))
  }

  return widgets;  
}
```

I would like to achieve the same thing without needing to make a function and instead have the code of the function as the parameter.

So what i'm looking for is a way to do something more like this:

```dart
Row(children: {
  final widgets List<Widget> = [];

  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    widgets.add(Text(numbers[i]))
  }

  return widgets;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use List.generate:

```
Row(children:
  List<Widget>.generate(
    numbers.length,
    (int index) {
      return Text('${numbers[index]}');
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: `List.generate` is designed to do precisely what used to be done with adding items to an empty list in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method

```
final List<Widget> listWidget = [];
Row(children: widgets.map((e) => e).toList()),
```

Answer (score 0):

I will encourage you to use `initState` if possible. Also, You can follow  @Jim's answer with `List.generate`.

And now, about the approach you are trying to use is called [`anonymous`/`inline function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62835171/10157127),

```dart
Row(
  children: () {
    // dont prefer doing heavy operatrion
    final List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      widgets.add(Text(numbers[i]));
    }
    return widgets;
  }(),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

check this ->

```
Row(children: generateWidgets(numbers))

List<Widget> generateWidgets(List<String> numbers){
   return numbers.map((e){
     return Text(e.toString());
  }).toList();
}
```