# Dart: What's the best practice between using ternary and if conditions in a widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been wondering what's the best practice for conditional widget trees between using ternaries and if-else-blocks.

Following guides online, I feel people use mostly ternaries but I find them quite unreadable when they exceed a single line :

[image: double ternary]

So I tend to create a fonction and make an if-else-block when my ternary are too long :

```
floatingActionButton: selectedLicences.isEmpty //
          ? Container()
          : LicencesWidget(selectedLicences: selectedLicences)
```

```
Widget _buildFAB(List<X> licences) {
    if (licences.isEmpty) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return LicencesWidget(selectedLicences: licences);
    }
  }
```

What's the best practice?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, which is not really suitable for this website. Whether code is readable is subjective. As for myself I prefer ternaries and don't find them unreadable when using proper indentation. Also, an objective reason to use ternaries is that they can be used directly after `child:`, which you can't do with if-else

Answer (score 1):

```
floatingActionButton: selectedLicences.isEmpty ? Container()
      : LicencesWidget(selectedLicences: selectedLicences)`
```

This is the best practice for sort conditions as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary is [Conditional expressions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) and [if-else](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#if-and-else) are statements.

Sometimes on widget tree if-else won't work, because it seeks for expression.
Like you cant use conditional if-else statements on `MaterialApp`'s `home` and scaffold's body

```dart
/// theses wont work
 MaterialApp(
   home: if(1<4) Text("") else Text('') 
   home: Scaffold(body: if(1<4) Text("") else Text(''),) 
or 
  Text(1 < 4 ? Text("") : Text(''))
```

But If you use ternary expression here it will work

```dart
body: 1 < 4 ? Text("") : Text('')
```

Inside a Column widget or the widget that takes children, you can use  conditional if-else statement.

You can check [Benefits of ternary operator vs. if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4192225/10157127)

**In summery:** Not all the time you can use if-else statement inside a widget, you will need to provide expression in that case. I prefer using ternary expression over if-else statements.

Also, you can check about [inline function,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62834933/10157127) [It is recommended not to do heavy operation]

```dart
  home: () {
        if (1 < 4) {
          return Text("");
        } else {
          return Text('');
        }
      }(),
```

---

About your snippet answer I will pass null instead of empty container.

```dart
floatingActionButton: selectedLicences.isEmpty
      ? null
      : LicencesWidget(selectedLicences: licences)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
floatingActionButton: selectedLicences.isEmpty ? const SizedBox.shrink()
          : LicencesWidget(selectedLicences: selectedLicences)
```

Using `const SizedBox.shrink()` is recommended when null cannot be returned. It will also improve performance as it can be set as compile constant.

As per the question whether to use if or ternary, It's the preference of the developer but most people stick to ternery for conditional widget builds.